# Saving DNS response in assembly using syscalls

Tags: linux, sockets, assembly, dns, x86

So I am wanting to learn more about DNS and I am wanting to use assembly to accomplish the task.

I noticed in tcpdump that my request appears to be accurate and I receive a response back, but my code doesn't know how to handle this.

I looked on a few sites and it looks like a recvfrom should be used , but I don't understand how I would call that function. Another answer I see is to use DUP2 and from what I understand it redirects stdin,out and err . From what I have been reading , I should manipulate sockcall ( 0x66 ) to call the recvfrom and get the data that has been sent to me. Most of the examples are using TCP and don't quite fit here since I am using UDP for the DNS.

Here is my code which queries google for example.com

```
nop
nop
nop
nop

; we create a socket fd, using again syscall 0x66 and argument SYS_SOCKET so ebx = 1  
push   0x66
pop    eax
push   0x1 
pop    ebx
xor    ecx,ecx
push   ecx
; but this times it will be a SOCK_DGRAM UDP, so 0x2 as argument 
push   0x2  
push   0x2 
mov    ecx,esp
int    0x80
; saving fd 
push 0x08080808 ; 8.8.8.8 ; I love that this doesn't really need to be backwards.
;push 0x0100007F            ; 0100007F 1.0.0.127 for testing...

xor edx,edx
mov dh, 0x35  ; port 53; comment this for variable port 
push dx       ; comment this for variable port 
              ;  push word PORT ; UNcomment this for variable port 
push word 0x2 ; 

mov ecx,esp   ; save pointer to ecx 
push 0x10     ; addrlen 
push ecx      ; pointer to sockaddr 
push eax      ; fd received previously 
mov ecx,esp   ;  
mov esi,eax   ; save fd for next call 
xor eax,eax 
mov al,0x66  
add bl,0x2   
int 0x80


    ; now we send a UDP packet to open stateful firewall :] 
xor eax,eax
mov al,0x66  ; ssize_t send(int sockfd, const void *buf, size_t len, int flags);
push 0x00000001       
push 0x00010000
push 0x6d6f6303
push 0x656c706d
push 0x61786507
push 0x00000000
push 0x00000100
push 0x0001AAAA


mov edx,esp ; Move the string to EDX so we can send it. 
xor ecx,ecx
push ecx  
push 64 ; size of message to be sent is 8
push edx 
push esi 
mov ecx,esp
xor ebx,ebx 
mov bl,0x9 
int 0x80 


mov ebx,esi
xor ecx,ecx
mov cl,0x2

loop:   ;Not sure if this is needed at all
; syscall dup2 
mov    al,0x3f
int    0x80
dec    ecx
jns loop

xor esi,esi
push   esi 
mov    edx,esp
push   ebx
mov    ecx,esp
int    0x80
nop
nop
nop
```

Comment: On a `connect()`ed UDP socket, you could just use `read()`, I think.  Oh, the notes in `recvfrom(2)` say that `read` won't consume a zero-length datagram, and will leave it pending.  Anyway, have you tried using `strace` to see what system calls your code is making?  `mov al, 0x3f` / `int 0x80` depends on the high bytes of EAX being zero, but that might not be the case if the previous `int 0x80` returned an error (`-errno`).

Comment: Have you tried writing this in C to get a handle on the system calls, before you attempt an asm version?  It sounds like you aren't sure what system calls you even need to use.  It's going to be easier to to use C to create and manipulate structs as local variables even if you're totally comfortable with asm.  (Unless you don't know C?)  I know both C and asm very well (but haven't done UDP networking for a long time), and I'd still be worried that I'd make a silly mistake in asm and spend a long time thinking the system call didn't do what I wanted.  (Although `strace` helps avoid that.)

Comment: I am on my way to work. I have a working example in python and C I also know . I just wasn't sure on the UDP side of things. I will try the read from socket though when I can. I should also mention I have done things like thin in asm using tcp though. Perhaps I am over thinking it.

Comment: If you have a working version *of this* in C, then it should be straightforward to translate to asm.  Again, use `strace` to debug.  (And don't forget to considers what will happen if one of the system call returns `-errno` on failure.  Depending on how the code will be used, you might not care and just let that break everything else including getting `-ENOSYS` from later calls with the wrong EAX)

Comment: But anyway, `recv` has fewer args than `recvfrom`, just `read` with an extra `flags`.  It might be a good choice for a connected socket.  It's equivalent to `recvfrom` with NULL for the remote-address struct output/len.  `dup2` just duplicates a file descriptor; it works on anything.  If you `dup2(fd, 1)`, that redirects stdout to `fd`, but you can dup between any pair of FDs without any of them being stdin/out/err.

Comment: Why specifically assembly? Just to learn or for any specific reason? It may not be the first most simple case to handle DNS packets, as they can be tricky in many aspects (fragmentation, name compression, EDNS, etc.). Also remember that the DNS uses UDP **and** TCP (and not just for AXFR replies, potentially for any request).

Comment: Yes, I remember it's UDP ) This is why the code is using a UDP socket ). So far , I haven't received anything compressed , but I chose x86 because I want I poorly know linux asm and I don't know DNS too well.. I always choose a small project to learn something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how it's done .

```
;Author : Krash

section     .text
global      main   ;must be declared for linker (ld)




; SOCKETCALL PARAMS You can pass a value to EBX to utilize one of these functions. 

; #define SYS_SOCKET      1               /* sys_socket(2)                */
; #define SYS_BIND        2               /* sys_bind(2)                  */
; #define SYS_CONNECT     3               /* sys_connect(2)               */
; #define SYS_LISTEN      4               /* sys_listen(2)                */
; #define SYS_ACCEPT      5               /* sys_accept(2)                */
; #define SYS_GETSOCKNAME 6               /* sys_getsockname(2)           */
; #define SYS_GETPEERNAME 7               /* sys_getpeername(2)           */
; #define SYS_SOCKETPAIR  8               /* sys_socketpair(2)            */
; #define SYS_SEND        9               /* sys_send(2)                  */
; #define SYS_RECV        10              /* sys_recv(2)                  */
; #define SYS_SENDTO      11              /* sys_sendto(2)                */
; #define SYS_RECVFROM    12              /* sys_recvfrom(2)              */
; #define SYS_SHUTDOWN    13              /* sys_shutdown(2)              */
; #define SYS_SETSOCKOPT  14              /* sys_setsockopt(2)            */
; #define SYS_GETSOCKOPT  15              /* sys_getsockopt(2)            */
; #define SYS_SENDMSG     16              /* sys_sendmsg(2)               */
; #define SYS_RECVMSG     17              /* sys_recvmsg(2)               */
; #define SYS_ACCEPT4     18              /* sys_accept4(2)               */
; #define SYS_RECVMMSG    19              /* sys_recvmmsg(2)              */
; #define SYS_SENDMMSG    20              /* sys_sendmmsg(2)              */


;The Message We want to send.



   ;DNS HEADER;
   ; AA AA - ID
   ; 01 00 - Query parameters
   ; 00 01 - Number of questions
   ; 00 00 - Number of answers
   ; 00 00 - Number of authority records
   ; 00 00 - Number of additional records
   ; DNS QUESTION --
   ; 07 - 'example' has length 7, ;so change this to be the length of domain ; keep in mind there are not '.' in the question.
   ; 65 - e
   ; 78 - x
   ; 61 - a
   ; 6D - m
   ; 70 - p
   ; 6C - l
   ; 65 - e

   ; 03 - subdomain '.com'  length 03  ; change this to be the length of type.

   ; 63 - c
   ; 6F - o
   ; 6D - m

   ; 00    - zero byte to end the QNAME 
   ; 00 01 - QTYPE 
   ; 00 01 - QCLASS




   ; DNS ANSWER! This is What We Want to receive ;
   ; aa aa
   ; 81 80
   ; 00 01
   ; 00 01
   ; 00 00
   ; 00 00
   ; 07 65
   ; 78 61
   ; 6d 70
   ; 6c 65
   ; 03 63
   ; 6f 6d
   ; 00 00
   ; 01 00
   ; 01 c0
   ; 0c 00
   ; 01 00
   ; 01 00
   ; 00 12
   ; 8d 00
   ; 04 

   ; IP ADDRESS IN HEX -- 93.184.216.34
   ; 5d
   ; b8 
   ; d8
   ; 22



main:                                         
    ; we create a socket fd, using again syscall 0x66 and argument SYS_SOCKET so ebx = 1  
    push   0x66
    pop    eax
    push   0x1 
    pop    ebx
    xor    ecx,ecx
    push   ecx
    ; but this times it will be a SOCK_DGRAM UDP, so 0x2 as argument 
    push   0x2  
    push   0x2 
    mov    ecx,esp
    int    0x80 ; SYS_SOCKET
    ; saving fd on the stack ; In reality I think I will save the port here instead 
    push eax


    push 0x08080808 ; 8.8.8.8 ; I love that this doesn't really need to be backwards.
    ;push 0x0100007F            ; 0100007F 1.0.0.127 for testing...

    xor edx,edx
    mov dh, 0x35  ; port 53; comment this for variable port 
    push dx       ; comment this for variable port 
                  ; push word PORT ; UNcomment this for variable port 
    push word 0x2 ; 




    mov ecx,esp   ; save pointer to ecx 
    push 0x10     ; addrlen 
    push ecx      ; pointer to sockaddr 
    push eax      ; fd received previously 
    mov ecx,esp   ;  
    mov esi,eax   ; save fd for next call 
    xor eax,eax 
    mov al,0x66  
    add bl,0x2   ; BL  = 3 SYS_CONNECT
    int 0x80      ;CALL  SYS_CONNECT


    ; now we send a UDP packet to open stateful firewall :] 
    xor eax,eax
    mov al,0x66   

     push 0x00000001 ; Origional Working request to google dns for example.com
     push 0x00010000
     push 0x6d6f6303
     push 0x656c706d
     push 0x61786507  
     push 0x00000000
     push 0x00000100
     push 0x0001AAAA   ; This is the DNS HEADER above in little endian order.


    mov edx,esp ; Move the string to EDX so we can send it. 
    xor ecx,ecx
    push ecx  
    push 64 ; size of message to be sent is 8
    push edx 
    push esi 
    mov ecx,esp
    xor ebx,ebx 
    mov bl,0x9 
    int 0x80     ;CALL SYS_SEND

    mov eax,  3 ; Prepare for SYSCALL_READ
    mov ebx,  3 ; 
    mov ecx, esp
    mov edx, 100
    int 0x80   ;CALL SYSCALL_READ

    add esp, eax
    sub esp, 4 
    mov eax ,[esp]
    push eax ; Probably not needed, I just want to ensure it's saved on the stack for further use..
```

Comment: This answer would be more useful to future readers with a text description of some key points.  Also, DF is guaranteed to be clear on function entry (required/guaranteed by the ABI), so you don't need `cld`.  Also, your program doesn't use any "string" instructions like `stos` or `movs`, so your program doesn't depend on how DF is set anyway.

Comment: Yes, I agree . I will clean up the answer tonight.